# Jmeter: Wait for threads to complete previous steps

Tags: jmeter

I have created a JMeter script for load testing and has following steps,

```
Login
Step 1
Step 2
Step 3
Logout
```

I want to perform load test for "Step 3" with 5 users. If i start the scripts with 5 users, the previous steps i.e. login, Step 1 and Step 2  may have different response time and Step 3 will not be triggered at same time.

Is there a way to configure JMeter like below,

```
Login
Step 1
Step 2
<Wait for all threads/user to complete Step 2>
Step 3
Logout
```

Comment: Why you want step3 to be execute in the same time?

Comment: That is because step 3 performs actual task and previous steps collects the data required to perform step 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [Synchronising Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Synchronizing_Timer) as a child of the `Step 3`, this way JMeter will pause the threads until specified number is reached so it will act as a "rendezvous point".